# Parallel.ForEach local finally without partition

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

In C# Parallel.ForEach localFinally gets called for each partition and not for each iteration, how can we make it to get called for each iteration and not for a partition?

In below example, if we run it it just add one item in the results collection even if trades collection, and hence the iteration, has more than 1 item in it.

```
 Parallel.ForEach(trades, parallelOptions,
                    // Loop Init
                () =>
                {
                    var result= new Result();
                    return result;
                },
                    // Loop Body
                (trade, loopState, index, result) =>
                {

                    result= new Result();

                    return result;
                },
                    // Loop Completion
                result=>
                {
                    lock (_lockObj)
                    {
                        results.Add(result);
                        Interlocked.Add(ref count, 1);
                    }
                });
```

How do we make above local finally to get called for each iteration?

Comment: The loop body code seems wrong..extra `)` and returns `tradeLevelResult` that is not declared

Comment: thanks! corrected. but what about the actual question? any way achieve it?

Comment: "In C# Parallel.ForEach localFinally gets called for each partition and not for each iteration" - This is exactly what it is documented to do. If you want to do something on each iteration, do it in `body`, which is called for each iteration.

Comment: Yeah, I want it to get called for each iteration and not for a partition, is it possible?

Comment: No, because *that's not what it is for*. Your repeated logic goes in `body`.

Comment: OK, So I have to create a list for each partition and then add results into it in body and then add in the final results set.

Comment: You are already creating a `Result` object for each task - you need to process the `trade` in the body adding it to the local `result` and you should be ok (if I am understanding correctly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783538%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> localInit - The function delegate that returns the initial state of
>   the local data for each task.
>
> body - The delegate that is invoked once per iteration.
>
> localFinally - The delegate that performs a final action on the local state of each task.

For each partition,

- `localInit` is called once
- `body` is called zero or more times, depending on how many items the partition processes.
- `localFinally` is called once

You need to do your per-item logic in `body`. If you want to aggregate the results, you should keep a local list for each partition.

```
Parallel.ForEach(trades, parallelOptions,
  // Loop Init
  () =>
  {
    // This creates one list per partition
    return new List<Result>(); // Becomes list
  },
  // Loop Body
  (trade, loopState, index, list) =>
  {
    // Only add the results to the local list for this partition
    list.Add(new Result());
    return list;
  },
  // Loop Completion
  list=>
  {
      lock (_lockObj)
      {
          // Merge the local list from each partition into the shared results list
          results.AddRange(list);
          Interlocked.Add(ref count, list.Count);
      }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks!! that's what I also figured :)